# Trying to find 12 week average by weekday basis

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to find 12 weeks average through same weekday.

Example:

[weekday sale](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KWTnf.png)

So basically I need the average based on the number of stores having net > 0. for yellow color, it should be total/11 as there is no sale for 02-07-16

I have written this query but it doesn't work properly. Could you guys please help me?

```
SELECT   Store_DateJoined.StoreKey, Store_DateJoined.RestaurantName,  Store_DateJoined.Ownership, Store_DateJoined.DateKey, 

Sales_Summary.Net, Sales_Summary.[LastWeek_Net],

(SELECT  AVG(Net) AS AVGNET
FROM   (SELECT     TOP (12) Net
                   FROM  DailySummary AS FB INNER JOIN
                  DimDate ON FB.DateKey = DimDate.DateKey
                   WHERE  datename(WEEKDAY, TransactionDate) IN (select datename(WEEKDAY, TransactionDate) from [NandosDW].[dbo].[DailySummary]) and   (FB.StoreKey = Store_DateJoined.StoreKey) AND (FB.DateKey <= Store_DateJoined.DateKey) AND 
                                          (DimDate.DayNameOfWeek = Store_DateJoined.DayNameOfWeek) AND (FB.DateKey >= (FB.DateKey - 84))

                   ORDER BY FB.DateKey, StoreKey DESC) AS WAVGNET) AS [Week12_Net], 
                   Store_DateJoined.FullDate, Store_DateJoined.DayNameOfWeek, Store_DateJoined.FinancialWC, Store_DateJoined.strFinancialWeek

FROM   Sales_Summary RIGHT OUTER JOIN Store_DateJoined LEFT OUTER JOIN 
   DimLFL ON Store_DateJoined.StoreKey = DimLFL.StoreKey AND Store_DateJoined.DateKey = DimLFL.DateKey ON 
   Sales_Summary.RedCatID = Sore_DateJoined.StoreKey AND 
   Sales_Summary.DateKey = Store_DateJoined.DateKey
```

I havent included the joins in this query, but they are present

Comment: where is the DDL,DML ?

Comment: plz provide your full sql query or the particular error/problem you have on this.

Comment: please check the edited code